# how do i prevent my program from getting deadlock but still keep mutual exclusion? (semaphores)

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

Currently working on a Homework question for operating systems class using semaphores and threads. very confused and was wondering if anyone here can help. the code i have so far:

```
01 travelToShop();    //puts thread to sleep between 1 and 1000 cycles
02 s1.acquire();      //lock semaphore, keeps mutual exclusion so no other
03 //thread writes to variable while another one is trying to do the same
04
05 if (numofcust==5){    //cant have more then 5 customers in a "shop"
06  s2.acquire();     //lock the shop, wait until shop reopens
07 }
08 numofcust++;          //increases variable telling class how many in shop
09 arriveAtShop();       //print statement saying ive arrived, if i arrived
10 //im technically in shop
11
12 s1.release();      //done writing to numofcust
13 sittingInShop();  //puts thread to sleep between 1 and 1000 cycles
14 //simulating having coffee
15
16 s1.acquire();     //refer to last "s1.acquire()"
17 numofcust--;      //simulating leaving the shop
18 if (numofcust==0){ //if shop empty
19 s2.release();     //open the shop
20 }
21 leaveShop();
22 s1.release();    //refer to last "s1.release()"
```

i know the problem is with line 6 and 12. once there are 5 customers in the shop, the rest of the customers have to wait (line 6). because i have to wait, the person who first got a hold of s1 is holding the semaphore which another customer has to acquire in order to leave (so no thread can release the lock that the thread is waiting on in order for that thread to release the lock for someone to leave.

ive tried doing the following :

```
05 if (numofcust==5){    //cant have more then 5 customers in a "shop"
06 s1.release(); //release the lock so others can write to numofcust and read
07  s2.acquire();     //lock the shop, wait until shop reopens
08  s1.acquire();    //reacquire the lock so i can write to numofcust again
09 }
```

but then i broke the mutual exclusion

How do i keep mutual exclusion where nobody can write to numofcust without the lock, but prevent the deadlock where one thread is holding the lock to numofcust because it is being held from waiting till the shop is open?

EDIT: if there are 5 customers in the shop, all the customers outside the shop have to wait till they all leave, but if there are less than 5 customers, they can go in as they please

Comment: i think what you are saying is just put it to sleep for 0 seconds then wake it up and check if its available, if not then try it again, in that case probably not because my professor said waking it up for nothing is very bad.

Comment: i believe that is what the given semaphore class is doing (or the wait class is doing?)

public void synchronized acquire(){
while (value<=0){
wait();
}
value--;
}

Comment: so far i asked he said semaphores, boolean, integers are good, what you got in mind?

Comment: and if i were to be able to use it (would have to run it by my professor) how would that help me? like i looked it up and i see all these get and set methods, but cant really see your perspective on what it will help me achieve

Comment: A common general solution to the problem is to use priorities.  Assign each lockable entity a priority level.  A thread holding a lock at level N may attempt to lock something at N+M (M positive), but may not attempt to lock something at N or below without first releasing locks with a priority level greater than the attempted level.  (Obtaining simultaneous locks on multiple things at a given level is allowed, with an all-or-nothing semantic.)  With careful assignment of levels to types of things, this can work quite naturally.

Comment: are you saying the semaphore should be assigned a priority level or a thread gets a priority level? if neither and your saying completely ignore semaphores, i cant do that because he requires semaphores to be used in your code.

Comment: AtomicIntegers allow you increment a number atomically doing `i++` is a read followed by a write and two threads can interleave both read 4 and write 5 when you really want 6. Mutual exclusion fixes that but an atomic increment is cleaner.

Comment: oh so your saying with an atomic integer nobody can read the integer until someone is done writing it? 

EX: thread 1 reads 5
thread 2 reads 5
thread 1 writes 6
thread 2 writes 6

versus

thread 1 reads 5 then writes 6
thread 2 reads 6 then writes 7

?

Comment: Yes but that probably won't help in this case because you need to know the current number of people in the shop and if that number has reached 5.

Comment: oh yeah i know i was saying as an example that nobody can read until someone is done writing and trying to see if i got the concept correct, did i?

Comment: Threads can read and write to the AtomicInteger at the same time but it detects if another thread tries to write at the same time and recovers http://crackingjavainterviews.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/what-is-atomicinteger-class-and-how-its.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two semaphores. The `Semaphore` object can have a variable number of permits. A semaphore can be acquired as many times are there are permits. A semaphore only blocks when all the permits have been acquired. If a permit is then released a blocked thread can wake up an acquire the newly freed permit.

A permit is not owned by a thread. Any thread can release any number of permits. This gives you a lot of flexibility when releasing a permit.

When leaving you need to vary how the permits are released based on the high watermark of people that have entered. When the high watermark is less than 5 release immediately. When the high water mark is 5 wait until the last person leaves and then release all the permits. This means counting the number of people in the shop separately to the semaphore permits and setting a flag once it reaches 5. The count and flag would need to be updated and checked by only one thread at a time.

Comment: so lets say i set the initial value of 5, 5 threads acquire the semaphore, how do i lock the shop so everyone else has to wait till all 5 leave?

the professor said if there are less than 5 in the shop, people can come in, but once there are 5, everyone has to wait till all 5 leave

Comment: yeah i wasnt specific enough (and i need to change it) that the shop has to be locked when there are 5 in the shop and only until all 5 are gone will other people be able to enter

Comment: I edited the answer to explain how to block until the shop is empty once 5 people are in there at the same time

Comment: so can i maybe make a shop thread that keeps checking if say there was 5 in the shop at one time and once the number of people in the shop is equal to 0 then i release the semaphore 5 times?

Comment: You don't need a shop thread. The people threads can update the current number and high watermark as they enter and leave the shop. After acquiring a permit on the shop semaphore and conditionally releasing permits.

Comment: I wouldn't release the semaphore 5 times. I would release 5 permits at once. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release(int)

Comment: i see what you mean however the problem is that my professor gave us a specific semaphore class so its not  the semaphore library that i have access to (aka dont have access to that method)

also still little confused about the high watermark, is that also a method of the semaphore library?

Comment: No I just mean you need to keep track of if the number of current customers ever reaches 5.

Comment: i ended up figuring out the problem using your suggestion (thank you) but now i need to figure out how to keep it so no thread skips another, but ill have to ask my professor for that, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

@MattChampion's answer is good, but I just want to point out that there's often more than one way to solve a problem.

Another way to solve this one, if you were unable to use the `Semaphore` class, would be to use a `BlockingQueue`:

Put five "tokens" in the blocking queue at the start of the program.  A token could be any object.  (e.g., `Object token = new Object();`)  Then, make sure each customer thread takes a token from the queue before entering the shop, and returns the token to the queue after leaving the shop.

If a thread tries to take a token when the queue is empty (five customers are in the shop), it will be blocked until a token becomes available.

Blocking queues are a powerful abstraction that can be used in a lot of ways besides just being a pipeline that passes objects from one thread to another.

Comment: i do like your idea and i see where you are going, however then it wouldnt require me using a semaphore class, which in that case i would do the homework wrong, thank you for that input though